Check if a file exists with string concatenation in batch
I have files in folders with names 00001_* to 99999_*. Not all will exist. I don't want to check all 99999 files. That would be a waste of time. Working with increments, higher and lower limits would be more efficient.
Apologies this is my first real stab at batch. I have a lot of files I need to delete or move.
The following will give results but I need to expand on it.
@echo off
set /p ll=lowerlimit?
set /p i=increment?
set /p ul=upperlimit?

for /l %%x in (%ll%,%i%,%ul%) do (
    if exist "c:\users\username\folder\subfolder\000%%x_0.jpg" (
        echo "000%%x_0.jpg file found") else (echo "000%%x_0.jpg file does not exist")
)

:end
pause

There is a big bug eg the file 00001_0.jpg exists.
My script is silly as it would be checking if 0001_0.jpg exists (when 00001_0.jpg exists) and again for names greater than two digits eg it would be checking for 000100_0.jpg when the file 00100_0.jpg could exist. It would be useful to store values in an array, know how to handle strings correctly in batch and remove or delete as appropriate

Perhaps you could also use findstr.exe to retrieve all of your files in a single for loop too. For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "%UserProfile\folder\subfolder\?????_0.jpg" /A:-D /B 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IR "^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]_0\.jpg$"') Do Echo %%G. Obviously once verified, you can change the Echo as needed. If you wanted just the leading four character files then use ????_0.jpg with "^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]_0\.jpg$".

There can be used the following batch file to search for files with number 1 to 99999 with always five digits left to _0.jpg:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ValueStart=1"
set "ValueIncrement=1"
set "ValueLast=99999"
set /P "ValueStart=Start value (default: %ValueStart%): " 
set /P "ValueIncrement=Increment by: (default: %ValueIncrement%): "
set /P "ValueLast=Last value (default: %ValueLast%): "

set "FolderPath=%USERPROFILE%\folder\subfolder"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%G in (%ValueStart%,%ValueIncrement%,%ValueLast%) do (
    if %%G LSS 100000 (
        set "FileName=0000%%G"
        set "FileName=!FileName:~-5!_0.jpg"
    ) else set "FileName=%%G_0.jpg"
    if exist "!FolderPath!\!FileName!" (echo Found file: !FileName!) else echo Not exist: !FileName!
)
endlocal

pause
endlocal

Another and a bit more efficient solution as suggested by dave_thompson_085 on ValueLast being always for sure less than 100000 and ValueStart being less than ValueLast (and of course not negative) is:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ValueStart=1"
set "ValueIncrement=1"
set "ValueLast=99999"
set /P "ValueStart=Start value (default: %ValueStart%): " 
set /P "ValueIncrement=Increment by: (default: %ValueIncrement%): "
set /P "ValueLast=Last value (default: %ValueLast%): "

set "FolderPath=%USERPROFILE%\folder\subfolder"
set /A ValueStart=100000+ValueStart
set /A ValueLast=100000+ValueLast

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%G in (%ValueStart%,%ValueIncrement%,%ValueLast%) do (
    set "FileName=%%G"
    set "FileName=!FileName:~1!_0.jpg"
    if exist "!FolderPath!\!FileName!" (echo Found file: !FileName!) else echo Not exist: !FileName!
)
endlocal

pause
endlocal

I recommend reading:

How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?
Safe number comparison in Windows batch file

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

echo /?
endlocal /?
for /?
if /?
pause /?
set /?
setlocal /?


A somewhat shorter way to pad when all numbers are less than a known power of 10, here 10000, is set/a lo=10000+lo & set/a hi=10000+hi & for /L %%i in (!lo!,1,!hi!) do ( set "t=%%i" & echo or use !t:~1! ) with enabledelayedexpansion
